# Why do we have to 'suggest improvement' on the Workplace instead of just commenting?

Tags: support, comments

I just realized that I cannot comment on questions (or answers) on The Workplace. I was just about to simply ask why, then I realized that I actually **can** comment, but the wording is different (and got me confused).

Instead of having 'comment' we have 'suggest improvement'.

Any reason to that?

Comment: Dupplicate maybe, except its not concerning my own question, so I wasn't able to relate. Ok though.

Comment: People happily downvoting on that, I don't get it. Just leave it alone maybe ? will have the same result. StackE so welcoming as usual. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an experiment conducted by SE staff to try and reduce the number of off topic comments. See [the official announcement post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/experiment-running-a-comment-by-any-other-name) for further details.

This experiment has been run on IPS and other sites before.

Comment: Ok ! Well I do understand the reason, and I think it is a good reason indeed, but as Im habit to 'comment' (while Im not commenting much), I got really confused by that. Now, I know ! thanks

Comment: @DevMoutarde if the experiment produces good results, I believe the plan is to roll it out everywhere, at which point things like help pages would get adjusted to match.  So the confusion should be temporary, if that's any consolation.